# Inheritance id in payment module

Tags: inheritance, odoo-10

I wanna inherit id in payment module and change the properties of the field from read only "yes" to "False".

I used a method one in inheritance,  created another module and made the changes but it didn't work .

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword `attributes` which helps to change attributes of an existing field.

Try either one of below method.

```xml
  <record model="ir.ui.view" id="payment_paypal_option_config">
        <field name="model">account.config.settings</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="payment.payment_acquirer_installation"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//div[@name='configure_payments_button']" position="attributes">
                <attribute name="invisible">0</attribute>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

**OR**

```xml
  <record id="view_badge_wizard_grant_employee" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">gamification.badge.user.wizard.form.inherit</field>
        <field name="model">gamification.badge.user.wizard</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="gamification.view_badge_wizard_grant" />
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <data>
                <field name="user_id" position="attributes">
                    <attribute name="invisible">True</attribute>
                </field>

            </data>
        </field>
    </record>
```